# How to write NUL to all log files in a folder using windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, nul

I have multiple log files that start as ABC_.log in a windows environment. I want to clean that file   (like writing /dev/null to file in linux). I need to do it through command line.

What I tried:

```
cmd:$ break > ABC_*.log
```

and

```
cmd:$ type NUL > ABC_*.log
```

Error:

```
 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can't be done via wildcard (not possible to redirect to more than one file at a time). Use a `for` loop to process each file on it's own:

```
for %%a in (ABC_*.log) do (
  break>"%%a"
)
```

or directly on command line:

```
 for %a in (ABC_*.log) do  break>"%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to empty a file in UNIX/Linux:

```
rm <filename>
touch <filename>
```